# Sampling and digitization of time series

Tags: matlab

There is a time series of 100 data points(say). I wish to assign symbols of 0 1 2 for each unique data point. The issue is I have tried but got stuck since no matter I specify the symbols,the program just outpits probability of 1's and 0's. The following is the issue

1. The statement

> s=x(:,1) > 0.5;

outputs a binary result 0,1 . So,how do I create multiple partitions / discretization so that apart from 0,1 other numerals can also be assigned.

> Is there any other way to symbolize and partition?

Comment: Have a look at the `histc` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way to do this would be something like:

```
s=zeroes(size(x,1), 1);
s(x>=BP(1) & x<BP(2)) = 1;
s(x>=BP(2)) = 2;
etc.
```

where BP is your list of break points (i.e., the edges of the partitions). That would make everything below BP(1)=0, things between BP(1) and BP(2) =1, and entries above BP(2) = 2;

I imagine something like this ought to work too:

```
s = zeroes(size(x,1), 1];
for ii=1:length(BP)
   idx = x > BP(ii);
   s(idx) = s(idx) + 1;
end
```

You've got more options if there are some constraints on your data and/or bin size. You might consider some clever combination of multiplication, division and rounding/truncating. For example, suppose your data was all in the range [0, 1) and you wanted it divided into twenty evenly spaced bins. Then, you could do something like:

```
s = floor(x(:,1) .* 20);
```

which would make s take values between 0 and 19. If your data wasn't already in that interval, you could obviously rescale it first:

```
data = x(:,1);
data = data - min(data);
data = data ./ (max(data) + eps(max(data))); 
s = floor(data .* 20);
```

Note that here, the normalizing factor in line 3 is not max(data), but the next largest number that matlab can represent. We do that so that there are 20 groups and not 21.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am unable to understand the meaning of breakpoints.Are they coordinates OR any arbitrary number depending on my data set (BP(1)=0.5 say,BP(2)=1.5 etc).

Comment: Further, I quite did not follow the x,y concept.Could you be kind enough to elaborate on that also,what it means and how to determine the BP's.

Comment: By breakpoints, I meant the edges of your partitions; they could be whatever number you choose. For the second, example, I should have stuck with the conventions in your post. I'll try editing it to make it clearer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.However, some doubts still persist. (A)Is there a way to determine the breakpoints in general without looking at the data set? (B)What if I want to assign a range of points say BP1=0.5 then all data points in range 0-0.5 fall under BP1; BP2=1 then all data points in range 0.5-1 classify under BP2 and so on.

Comment: That's exactly what the first snippets do. You'd do something like BP=[0.5, 1]. They don't come from the data at all--you've got to provide them. The only trick here is what matlab calls "logical indexing". That is, instead of providing a numeric index (i.e., a(4) gets you the 4th element of the array), you can also provide a list of ones/zeros (i.e., true and falses), so a(logical(0,0,0,1)) also gets you the 4th element. This works as both and lvalue and an rvalue, so you can use them to get or set variables.

Comment: *Threshold* is probably a better word here, since it won't be confused with debug breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `x(:,1) > 0.5;` is creating a logical index: `true (1)` where the condition is satisfied, `false (0)` where it is not.  You can use this logical index to grab values from the original vector where the condition is satisfied.

```
logical_index = x(:,1) > 0.5;
s = x(logical_index,1); %# select the subset of the matrix given by x > 0.5
```

`s` now contains the values from `x` that are greater than 0.5.

Beyond this, I can't understand what you're trying to do.  An small example data set would help (if you still need help, that is).

Edit: To find values appropriate for dividing your set up this way, take a look at [prctile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/prctile.html).  You can then apply any of the methods in the answers to figure out which elements fall into which category.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.As mentioned in Answer1,i intend to create partion in the data which spans say there are 10 points in range 0.5-1(so data points falling in this range will be denoted by symbol 1);another 10 ponts in 1-1.5(denoted by symbol 2) and so one.So,without looking at the data points is there way to describe the partitions so that they are valid for all cases?